# How to set barrierColor for all the dialogs in the flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog

I want to set the bariierColor for the dialog as `Colors.black54.withOpacity(0.3)`.

Now what the issue is, I need to set the same thing for all of the dialogs used in the app. It'll take much effort. Do anyone has a solution for which I can set at one place like themedata and I can set that for the whole app's dialog.

Here's the code I am using.

```
showDialog(
  barrierColor: Colors.black54.withOpacity(0.3),
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => AppAlertDialog(
      game: game, 
      dialogType: AlertDialogType.notification,
      // onButtonClick: ()=> showChallengeDialog(context)
    ),
);
```

Please help me as I am relatively new to Flutter.

Comment: can you provide the code with widget where you define `barierColor`?

Comment: @SimonSot, I've edited post and added the code I am using it.

Comment: `AlertDialogType` coming from some package or is it a custom widget? We need an endpoint where Theming can be applied

Comment: @SimonSot AlertDialogType is an enum. I am using custom dialog.

Comment: @Dude Can you help me defining the wrapper function with the barrierColor?